# Zend Framework/Quickstart: undefined constant APPLICATION_PATH

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hai

I got an error message

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant APPLICATION_PATH - assumed 'APPLICATION_PATH' in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 4

Notice: Use of undefined constant APPLICATION_PATH - assumed 'APPLICATION_PATH' in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 5
```

When i put below code in index.php:

```
set_include_path(
    'C:\wamp\www\Zend\' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/models' . 
    PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path() );
```

What is APPLICATION_PATH in This , shall i have to  write any thing rather than this....

Thanks  Very much

Comment: Hi, could you please use more descriptives titles, and not use the same title for two questions ? It would make things easier when reading through the questions list ; thanks :-)

Comment: See also [my attempt at a canonical answer for causes of this error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean/8025500#8025500).

Answer (score 4):

Re,

the application path is the application directory of your Zend project

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application/'));
```

see the [quick start](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart) for reference

Cheer