# Zend farme work Doubt2

Tags: php, html

I put this in to `php.ini`

```
include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;C:\wamp\zend\library"
```

`C:\wamp\:` here I put the zend frame work

when I run the WAMP sever , I seen a page as usual

How I check whether it's install or not,

How I start my work in the frame work

Comment: Hi, what I said on your other question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436828/zend-farme-work-doubt1 ) about using more descriptive titles, and differents titles for each question still stands : between "Zend farme work Doubt", "Zend farme work Doubt1", and "Zend farme work Doubt2", it's kind hard to find out what your questions are about, when going through the list of questions :-( Please, think to people reading your questions, and help us :-)

Comment: I voted to close this because this duplicates with your other questions. It's also really annoying that you don't listen to what people are trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the output of php_info() to see if you settings were applied as expected ...

also a [screencast](http://www.zendcasts.com/getting-started-with-zend-and-wamp-server/2009/06/) to let you get kick off.